# Что такое актуализация ветки при работе с git?

Tags: git, непрерывная-интеграция

Что такое актуализация ветки при работе с git? Чем актуализация отличается от обновления ветки? Как актуализация ветки связана с CI/CD?

Comment: В чём выражается актуализация ветки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без привязки к контексту трудно дать определения, т.к. разные авторы могут переводить и иметь ввиду разное.

Для себя я бы сказал, что:

**актуализация** - это получение последних изменений из сетевого репозитория. При этом, если были изменения в локальной ветке, то потребуется перебазирование (*rebase*) или слияние (*merge*).

**обновление** - это передача изменений ветки из локального репозитория в сетевой.

Понятия очень близкие, можно обновлять и локальную ветку, и актуализировать сетевую.

**CI/CD** - запрограммированные на автоматическое выполнения действия (сборка, тестирование, распространение), запускаемые в сетевом хранилище при очередном получении изменений (*commit*) в любой ветке. Это отдельный механизм, не является частью *Git*.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не могли бы вы уточнить ответ пояснив: 1) имеется ввиду получение последних изменений из ВЕТКИ MASTER (сетевого репозитория)? 2) В ежедневном проделывании этого и заключается Continuous Integration (для того чтобы не было больших мерж конфликтов когда локальная ветка будет мержиться в ветку master)?

Comment: 1) Изменения из любых веток. Допустим разрабатывается новый функционал в ветки `super_feat`, на основе этой ветки вы делаете что-то свое. В этом случае вы получаете изменения из ветки `super_feat`. При синхронизации (fetch) с удаленным репозиторием вы получаете все изменения всех веток, что/как использовать решать вам. Это не обязательно делать ежедневно.

Comment: 2) Подправил ответ. CI/CD - это технология, выполняющая специальные скрипты на отдельном сервере для автоматизации процесса создания ПО.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо! Правильно ли я понял, что хоть и не обязательно делать актуализацию ежедневно, но все же смысл Contunuous Integration заключается в том чтобы делать ее (актуализацию) достаточно часто для того чтобы код над которым программист работатет в своей локальной ветке не разошелся сильно с кодом в удаленной ветке и не пришлось бы резолвить много мерж конфликтов во время Pull Request?

Comment: Continuous Integration - это другой мир, к Git и обсуждаемой нами теме отношения не имеет. Наверное, вы думаете, что он означает совместную разработку, но это не так. Следующее, на что стоит обратить внимание это то, что если вам приходится решать много конфликтов, то в организации написания кода у вас что-то не так. Совместная разработка не означает пилить один файл, она о том, как решать зависимые задачи параллельно. Разбивайте на модули, делайте библиотеки. Цель должна быть решить задачу, а не решать конфликты. как-то так.